# Distribution of random variable $Y = (X + 1)^2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

Could you please help to solve the following problem:

> The random variable $X$ has a uniform distribution on the segment $[0,2]$. Find the density of the distribution of a random variable $Y = (X + 1)^2$.

My attempt (but it is obviously wrong):

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
(x+1)^2, & x \notin [0,2], \\
0, & x \notin [0,2].
\end{cases} $$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{2} (x+1)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
= \left[ (x+1)^2 \right]_{0}^{2}
= (x+1)^2 (2 - 0)
= 1. $$

\begin{align*}
&\implies \quad 2(x+1)^2 = 1 \\[0.5em]
&\implies \quad (x+1)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \\[0.5em]
&\implies \quad x^2 + 2x + \frac{1}{2} = 0 \\[0.5em]
&\implies \quad x_1 = \frac{-2 + 2^{1/2}}{2}, \quad x_2 = \frac{-2 - 2^{1/2}}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: @user264745, it makes little sense because my attempt is obviously wrong

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164)

Comment: @HannaBilous it's OK to show the wrong attempt here, it proves you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @HannaBilous If I understand correctly, why is this integration valid?

$$\int_0^2 (x+1)^2 dx = \left.(x+1)^2\right|_0^2$$

Comment: @peterwhy, Indeed, it is clearly not.  $\int_0^2 (x+1)^2\mathrm d x = \int_1^3 y^2\mathrm d y ={\left.\tfrac 13y^3\right\rvert}_{y=1}^{y=3}=\dfrac {26}3$

Comment: I'm ashamed. I was helping my brother solve this problem, and the studying probability theory has been a long time ago for me, and was very-very sleepy and forgot to take the integral from the definition  
Asking for help here was my last hope (and I wrote here for the first time, so there were so many problems with the design of the question), and I was pleasantly surprised how the community helped me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

$$ P (Y \leq u) = P((X+1)^2 \leq u) = P(X \leq \sqrt{u}-1)$$
Thus, using $F$ for the cummulative distribution function we have
$$F_Y (u) = F_x (\sqrt{u}-1)$$
The density $f$ is a derivative of $F$:
$$f_Y(u) = \frac{d}{du} F_X(\sqrt{u}-1) = F_X^\prime (\sqrt{u}-1) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$$
$$  = \frac{f_x\left(\sqrt{u}-1 \right)}{2\sqrt{u}}
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1}{4\sqrt{u}} & \;\;if\;\; & 1 \leq u \leq 9 
  \\
  0 & \;\; elsewhere
\end{array}
\right.
$$